# Login failure when using JWT and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to setup authentication using JWT using Angular as my front end and Spring as backend. I have the following **AuthenticationFilter** class for setting up JWT filter:

```
package com.atlas.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException;

public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        //System.out.println("filter");
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String authHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("Authorizatoin");
        //System.out.println(authHeader);
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            throw new ServletException("Missing or invalid Authorization header.");
        }
        String token = authHeader.substring(7);

        try
        {
            //security key needs to be changed before deployment
            Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("feb1atlaskey").parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
            req.setAttribute("claims", claims);
        }
        catch(SignatureException e)
        {
            throw new ServletException("Not a valid token");
        }
        chain.doFilter(req,res);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is my UserController class where the login check and setting Auth header happens:

```
package com.atlas.controller;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.atlas.entity.User;
import com.atlas.service.UserService;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    private final Map<String, List<String>> userDb = new HashMap<>();

    public UserController() {
        userDb.put("tom", Arrays.asList("user"));
        userDb.put("sally", Arrays.asList("user", "admin"));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public LoginResponse login(@RequestBody final UserLogin login)
        throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("In user controller");
        if (login.name == null || !userDb.containsKey(login.name)) {
            throw new ServletException("Invalid login");
        }
        return new LoginResponse(Jwts.builder().setSubject(login.name)
            .claim("roles", userDb.get(login.name)).setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "secretkey").compact());
    }


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void addUser(@RequestBody User u) {
        this.userService.addUser(u);
    }
        private static class UserLogin {
            public String name;
            public String password;
        }

        private static class LoginResponse {
            public String token;

            public LoginResponse(final String token) {
                this.token = token;
            }
        }
}
```

Now, when I do a login using simple form and make a POST request using Angular, its not reaching UserController. Its hitting the filter and throwing Servlet Exception as "Missing or invalid Authorization header".

I have also configured my app to add this filter in the chain as below:

```
package com.atlas.config;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class[]{AppConfig.class,SwaggerConfig.class,AuthenticationFilter.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/api/*"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        Filter [] singleton = { new CORSFilter(), new AuthenticationFilter() };
        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Am I missing some config here or making some terrible mistake.
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Authorization" header is mispelled:

Replace from:

```
String authHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("Authorizatoin");
```

To:

```
 String authHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("Authorization");
```

You may consider using Spring Framework constants for http headers to avoid such issues:

```
String authHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader(org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
```

Comment: Thank you Michael! I have changed the spelling but, still have the same problem. The request is not reaching the UserController class. (Also, I did Maven Update on Eclipse to refresh the context).

Comment: I dont have any errors when I launch the project, but this happens whenever the form tries to reach the login module.                          SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/febatlas] threw exception [Missing or invalid Authorization header.] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Missing or invalid Authorization header.

Comment: and what is the content of `authHeader`

Comment: Its null, as I am passing form values from login page. The token is yet to be created based on the form values.

Comment: So you should not check jwt when authenticating, you have to add a condition to test if the current url is the login page in your filter : `if ( req.getRequestURI().contains("/authenticate")){
            filterChain.doFilter(req, res);}`

Comment: Thank you. I thought so, but, how to forward my request from Filter to controller without compromising security. any good fixes?

Comment: You only bypass security when calling the authenticate api, for others api the jwt security filter will reject unauthorized calls and that's a good way of doing things. See an example here: https://github.com/RedFroggy/angular-spring-hmac/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/redfroggy/hmac/configuration/security/XAuthTokenFilter.java

Comment: Thank you again, will try that out now.

Comment: I have updated my code to the one you sent. That solved my issue of reaching to login page, now I am unable to reach the controllers after the login(rest calls). Any idea? Thanks again

Comment: can you post information of the http request : headers, url, etc